# network manager not listing wifi

Tags: linux, wifi, network-scan

I use NetworkManager command tool to scan for wireless networks is empty.

```
root@radxa:~# nmcli dev wifi list
SSID    BSSID   MODE    FREQ    RATE    SIGNAL  SECURITY    ACTIVE
root@radxa:~#
```

but is use **iwlist** scan is ok.

```
root@radxa:~# iwlist wlan0 scan
          Cell 01 - Address: 78:A1:06:7F:CF:C9
                    ESSID:"olivia"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=0/100  Signal level=7/100
```

linux version

```
Linux version 3.0.36+ (build@radxa-x1) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #6 SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 19 15:17:11 CST 2014
```

Why?help me plase.

Comment: Your question does not seem to have anything to do with programming for which Stack Overflow is dedicated. Other Stack Exchange sites, like [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) might be more suitable and your question would probably get more attention, and answers, there. Please see ["what topics are welcome here"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as well.

Answer (score 4):

What works for me is to add these lines to /etc/networks/interface.

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

reboot, wait 1-2 min during booting process and it works flawlessly. Got answer from this [link.](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1021210.html) I put this here for a shortcut.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You may also simply need `sudo apt install wpasupplicant`. After I did that, `sudo nmcli d wifi list` worked perfectly, no reboots needed.

Answer (score 0):

I Just found out that in my case the problem was probably originated by a wrong version of libcrypto that got installed with a smart card manager. ssh also had problems with it (that is how I found out). Have you messed up with libcrypto recently?
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A had the same problem with a Ubuntu 20.04, using the notebook internal wifi and a external USB wifi.

The only thing that solve was:

```
sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant.service
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158328/network-manager-not-listing-wifi